# Problem with command "rails generate model xxx"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I just created a ruby on rails project and I'm trying to generate a model with the command `rails generate model Car` and I'm getting this error:

```
~/Code/CarInfo (master) $ rails generate controller Test
```

> ```
> rbenv: version `ruby-2.3.7' is not installed
> ```

I tried updating and reinstalling rbenv with homebrew but it still doesn't work and I'm still getting the same error.

When I type ruby -v in the cli I am getting the same error as shown above.

Comment: Did you also view the [installation instructions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos) and run `rbenv init`, and follow the remaining installation instructions.

Comment: Yes! And now im getting ```Ignoring bindex-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.6.0
Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.2
Ignoring byebug-11.0.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 11.0.1
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.10.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)```

Comment: Try `which ruby`, `which gem`, and `which bundler` and post your results. Also, try `gem install bundler`. I suspect you've got ruby configured, but it's pointing back to the default "system ruby" version of bundler (because of the path in the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rbenv lets you switch between versions of ruby, but it doesn't install those versions for you. I'd suggest also installing [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) (which works with rbenv). Once you've done that, you should be able to run `rbenv install 2.3.7` and fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you! i already followed this guide but it still dosent work

Comment: What happens when you run `rbenv versions`?